# Javascript text file loading delay

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm loading a .txt file located on my server with this simple method:

```
function getFileFromServer(url, doneCallback) 
{
 console.time("getFileFromServer");
 var xhr;

 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
 xhr.open("GET", url, true);
 xhr.send();

 function handleStateChange() {
     if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
         doneCallback(xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.responseText : null);
     }
 }
 console.timeEnd("getFileFromServer");
}
```

I'm using it in this simple way, accordingly to this post: [Reading a txt file from Server, writing it to website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18603573/4304443)

```
function loadFile( url ) {
    console.time("loadFile");
    getFileFromServer(url, function(text) {
    if (text === null) {
        console.log("error-loading-file");
    }
    else {
        console.timeEnd("loadFile");
        doStuff(text);
    }
});
```

As you can see I've put the console.time to keep track of the timing. Here's what the browser console answer:

getFileFromServer: 1.744ms

loadFile: 18114.871ms

I'm not a javascript expert, and the only thing I can figure out to explain the timing difference is the argument passing(value vs reference in C++). 
Someone can explain me this difference in timing?

Comment: this is because of the `async` nature of the ajax calls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233633/understanding-asynchronous-code-in-laymans-terms

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `getFileFromServer` finishes very fast is that there is no real processing done. The function does not wait until the request returns from the server but **only registers the callback function** for when it does. That means it took 1.744ms to **send** the request, nothing more.

The `loadFile` function is measuring the time between sending the request and actually getting a response. That is the difference.